# How to detect if my search bar has been expanded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search bar that expands when you click on it. I am having an issue with the `opacity`. I need the `opacity` to be set to `0` until it is hovered over **or** expanded. Mine detects if they have hovered or not, however the second the users mouse pointer leaves the text area it turns transparent again.

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cfgqueww/).

How can I keep the opacity set to `0` *only* when the search bar is not expanded and set it to `1` in all other scenarios?

HTML:

```
<form class="search-container" action="#">
  <input id="search" type="text" class="search" name="q" />
  <label for="search"><span class="search-t">Go</span></label>
  <input type="submit" id="search-s" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.6s, border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s, box-shadow 0.6s;
    transition: width 0.6s, border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s, box-shadow 0.6s;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

    .search + label .search-t {
        color: black;
    }

    .search:hover {
        color: white;
        opacity: 1;
        background: #c8c8c8;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #3d4752;
    }

        .search:hover + label .search-t {
            color: white;
        }

    .search:focus {
        -webkit-transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.66, 1.39), border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s;
        transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.66, 1.39), border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
        cursor: text;
        width: 250px;
        border-radius: auto;
        background: #ebebeb;
        color: black;
    }

        .search:focus + label .search-t {
            color: black;
        }

    .search:not(:focus) {
        text-indent: -5000px;
    }

#search-s {
    position: relative;
    left: -5000px;
}

.search-t {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `opacity:1` to `search:focus`

```
.search:focus {
    opacity:1;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/cfgqueww/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `opacity:1;` to the `:focus` selector:

```
.search:focus {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.66, 1.39), border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s;
    transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.66, 1.39), border-radius 0.6s, background 0.6s;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: text;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: auto;
    background: #ebebeb;
    color: black;
    opacity:1;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfgqueww/2/)